# Cannot return database object.

Tags: postgresql, go

This is my code for working with postgres database.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

//Details required for connection
const (
    HOST     = "HOSTNAME"
    USER     = "USER"
    PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
    DATABASE = "DB"
)

func Create() (*sql.DB) {

    dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s", HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
    db,err  := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
    defer db.Close()

    if (err != nil) {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db
}


func main() {
    db := Create()
    querStmt, err := db.Prepare("select count(*) from table")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot prepare query\n")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    res, err := querStmt.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot execute query\n")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", res)
}
```

When running this code i am getting this error

```
Cannot prepare query
2016/03/09 16:57:23 sql: database is closed
```

If i run query from `Create()` then it works perfectly but doing same on db object returned by `Create()` inside `main()` is not working. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database is closed the moment you return from `Create` because your defer is inside it and not inside `main`. Move the defer to main and it should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks. It was a go noob mistake :P